# Get string from tag <a> using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this prettify html

```
         <a href="somepath">
          Text1
         </a>
         <span>
          |
         </span>
         <a href="somepath">
          Text2
         </a>
         <span>
          |
         </span>
         <a href="somepath">
          Text3
         </a>
```

I used this code:

```
cnta= len(res.findAll('a'))-1 //I used -1 because I have one extra a tag
cnt = 0
while cnt<cnta:
    res2 = res.find('a').text
    cnt+=1
    print res2
```

I want to take all 3 Texts but the result is 3 times "Text1"... I know that I not saying anyone to go to next but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop directly over the `findAll` results:

```
for elem in res.findAll('a'):
    print elem
```

The `.find()` method just returns the first element within `res` it finds, it doesn't continue the search from the last hit you found. So on each run through the loop it'll find the same element.

If you want to limit the number of results, use slice notation:

```
for elem in res.findAll('a')[:3]:
    print elem
```

Comment: It works but I have one extra 'a' that is included too... Can i somehow skip the last 'a'?

Comment: Updated; `findAll` returns a list so you can slice it.

Comment: Thank you... Sorry for noob question but I just today learn some basic python and didn't know how to slice list.. Thanks again..

Comment: If you just want to ignore the last element, `res.findAll('a')[:-1]` will be simpler than figuring out the length and using a positive slice.

Comment: @Loclip: See [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) for a good primer.